# Android keyboard immediately disappears in bootstrap or fabricjs input

Tags: android, html, twitter-bootstrap, fabricjs

I've made a web app that uses a Fabric JS canvas with an IText on it (so you can type text in it), and a Bootstrap JS ordinary textarea.

Activating either to start typing (so cursor appears) causes the Android keyboard to pop up and then immediately slide down again, thus making typing impossible.

This is on an Android 4.1.1 tablet, using latest versions of FabicJS, Bootstrap, Opera, Chrome, and the native Android browser. Behaviour is slightly different on native browser - keyboard stays up but switches to all caps mode, and then activates the browser address bar!

Anyone got any ideas please?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you able to edit the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Thanks but no I can't edit that because this is not for an installable app, it's for a website, so that file doesn't apply.

Comment: Yup and this is where cross platform dev has it's limitations. In native android it's a one-liner haha